# DJANGO Celery on Application Server + Mail server

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am trying to configure DJANGO + Celery on Application server with separate mail server.

Both servers has same files:

app_name/settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = "sqs://%s:%s@" % (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle','json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import timedelta
CELERY_ROUTES = {
                'mail.tasks.send_reminder_email_end_user': {'queue': 'scheduler'},
                'mail.tasks.send_all_daily_new_user_email': {'queue': 'scheduler'},
                'mail.tasks.send_notification_email': {'queue': 'scheduler'},
                'mail.tasks.send_new_post_daily_email': {'queue': 'scheduler'},
                'insightStat.tasks.save_stats_history_daily': {'queue': 'scheduler'},
                }

CELERY_DISABLE_RATE_LIMITS = True
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_reminder_email_daily': {
        'task': 'mail.tasks.send_reminder_email_end_user',
        'schedule': crontab(minute= 0,hour=7)
    },
    'update_stats_history_daily': {
        'task': 'insightStat.tasks.save_stats_history_daily',
        'schedule': crontab(minute= 0,hour=1)
    },
    'send_notification_email_weekly': {
        'task': 'mail.tasks.send_notification_email',
        'schedule': crontab(minute= 0,hour=8)
    },
    'send_digest_email_daily': {
        'task': 'mail.tasks.send_new_post_daily_email',
        'schedule': crontab(minute= 0,hour=8)
    },
    'send_daily_new_users': {
    'task': 'mail.tasks.send_all_daily_new_user_email',
    'schedule': crontab(minute= 0,hour=7)
    },
    'send_digest_email_weekly': {
        'task': 'mail.tasks.send_weekly_digest',
        'schedule': crontab(minute= 0,hour=8,day_of_week='Mon')
    },


}
```

mail/tasks.py file:

```
@shared_task(queue='scheduler')
def send_all_daily_new_user_email():
    apps = Application.objects.all()
    for app in apps:
        daily_new_user_email.delay(app)


@shared_task(queue='daily_user')
def daily_new_user_email(app):
    print "sending daily_new_user_email"
    if not app.digest_email:
        print "app digest is off, return"
        return
    if not app.owner.all():
        return
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    users= app.appuser.filter(created_at__gt=yesterday)
    users_count = users.count()
    owner = app.owner.all()[0]
    if users_count == 0:
        print "no new users for %s " % owner.email
        return
    recent_user = users[0]
    subject  = "%s new subscribers" % str(users_count)
    content_html = render_to_string('daily_new_users.html',locals())
    email = owner.email
    print sendEmail(NOTIFICATION_EMAIL,email,subject,content_html,content_html,'daily_new_users')
```

app_name/celery_task.py file contains:

```
app = Celery('app_name', backend='', broker='"sqs://%s:%s@" % (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)',
            include=['mail.tasks'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.start()    

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

where: scheduler is a Que on application server and daily_user is a Que on mail server. I am using supervisor to start celery workers

This is sending the mail multiple times to the user. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, can anyone brief about @shared_task?

Comment: how many times is it sending emails per run?

Comment: Can you verify you only have a single app defined? Have you checked to see whether your tasks are getting called multiple times (vs the email task itself being processed multiple times) ?